# Is the Device.Language column from Google Analytics OS language or Browser Langue?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

There is a device.language column from https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en. The given definition is "The language the device is set to use. Expressed as the IETF language code.".

But I want to confirm whether this means the OS language of the device or the browser language?

Answer (score 0):

It is the browser's configured, preferred language. There is no way for Google Analytics to know what is the OS language settings.

Comment: I am very new in google analytics, thanks for sharing your knowledge

Comment: Actually, I saw that the BigQuery Export schema does have device.operatingSystem("Macintosh" or "Windows") and device.operatingSystemVersion. So could GA possibly be able to get the OS language too?

Comment: No, it cant. It gets the OS type from the user agent string, but there is no such OS language there. The browser itself does not expose the system locale (and that is a good thing). Note however that, for the majority of users (not considering specific geographic areas), these two settings match.

Comment: Thanks again, this makes sense. But I aslo see device.language is specify as "the OS lanugage" in GA4 scheme.  Any thought on this? 
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846?hl=en

Comment: An article said GA4 Properties is not an upgrade to Universal Analytics — it is an entirely new version of Google Analytics. But I wonder whether this device.lanugae filed is a heraitge of what it was in the UA version.

Comment: The line is clear. If this "language" is something you get, server-side, from users browsing through the web, you can ONLY guess based on the "Accept-language:" http header which reflect the browsers' language preferences. Like I answered, there is NO way for GA or any other piece of JavaScript that runs on a browser, to reliably determine the users' operating system language. They call it 'device' to group the record nicely for you, that's all.

Comment: Alight, guess that is all I need. thanks！

Comment: @Aihua don't forget to accept the answer if it helped. And welcome to SO.